How to get Action Context in a request
How do I get an ActionContext from the current request?
I've tried several things like injecting an ActionContextAccessor like below and using it but it always returns null.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

var ctx = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>()

I also try creating the ActionContext myself but then I can't get its features such as the descriptors of the current controller and action
var actionContext = new ActionContext(HttpContext, HttpContext.GetRouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());


// then when I do something like this I get nothing

var httpAttributes = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetAttributes<HttpMethodAttribute>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

string entity = (actionContext.ActionDescriptor?.GetAttributes<RouteAttribute>().GetAwaiter().GetResult()).FirstOrDefault()?.Name;


